# How to disable ACES?

Tags: color-management

When I created a system variable OCIO with a path to aces 1.2 my Display Device changed to ACES by default and I can't choose the old sRGB with Filmic. How to disable ACES and switch to sRGB or vice versa? Is there a way not to delete that system variable OCIO?
[image]

When I start blender I see this log [image]

Comment: I think that message is telling you that your OCIO path only includes a path to ACES and no longer includes a path to sRGB.  I think you want a path with both.

Comment: Idk the path to sRGB. Do you know how to set it up?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the path.  It looks like there's a configuration file in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\datafiles\colormanagement\config.ocio that might be relevant.  (Replace c:\Program Files as appropriate and change \ to / on Un*x like systems.)

Answer (score 1):

You can start blender using a batch file in which to set the OCIO environment variable.

```
set OCIO=D:\Blender-ACES-Config\config.ocio
start "Blender (ACES workflow)" "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\blender.exe"
```

Or you can use my ACES config [in this repo](https://github.com/Ginurx/Blender-ACES-Config) which retains Blender filmic but with slightly differences caused by rendering color space.