# How to disable ACES in Blender 3.2 (further question)

Tags: color-management

I'm struggling to disable ACES even after installing the depository by Ginurx, linked in this thread: [How to disable ACES?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234413/how-to-disable-aces)

Please, if anyone here could give me a hand, this would be an immense relief. I need to enable the default profiles of Blender for a collaborative project that needs to be finished very soon and switching to ACES isn't possible for this case. However, I can't figure out how to edit the batch file for starting Blender 3.2 without ACES. I even tested putting a config.ocio file into the colormanagement folder, that a friend of mine shared with me, who doesn't have ACES installed at all, and my Blender 3.2 still launched with ACES as the color profile. I read the whole documentation here, but I still can't make it work: https://github.com/Ginurx/Blender-ACES-Config
I followed the installation Method 1.

Thank you for any tips and help in advance.

Comment: If you still have a backup copy of the original "colormanagement" folder, then you could simply rename the current one to, e.g. "colormanagement-ginurx" and copy the original "colormanagement" into the "datafiles" folder. If you do not have a backup copy, the simplest solution is probably to download the [portable version of Blender (blender-3.2.1-windows-x64.zip)](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.2/) as a separate copy without the modifications. What particular part are you having trouble with?

Comment: My colormanagement folder already contained ACES so the backup I have is kind of useless I guess. I will try to pull it form the portable version you sent. Thank you!

Comment: Even after replacing it with the one from the portable installation, my Blender still launches with ACES.

I'm not sure this plays any role in it. I also have Octane for Blender installed. But I'm not using it in this project.

Comment: It seems like another OCIO file over-writes it.
https://imgur.com/a/5y2sHUp

Comment: You probably have the `OCIO` environment variable set. You can open a command prompt in Blender's folder by typing `cmd` into the path bar of the Windows Explorer and pressing enter. Run `set OCIO=` and then `.\blender.exe`. Does that work?

Comment: Dear Robert, these replies mean a lot. We agreed that I will do my part in ACES and I already started recalculating the the rgb values of shaders etc, so now I need to manage it with ACES. I will however return to this in a week and try to make it work so that my Blender version would allow me to choose in the future. So if you don't mind, I will write back here in case it was still not working after the last tip from you. If there will be silence, it means I managed thanks to your advice. Be well!

Answer (score 0):

If you restored the `colormanagement` folder, Blender still works in ACES mode. It's much likely that your OCIO environment variable has been set, as [Robert Gützkow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/74827/robert-g%c3%bctzkow)
 mentioned.

You could open `cmd` and type `echo %OCIO%`.
If a path were to be printed, you have to delete the OCIO environment variable in [system settings](https://www.howtogeek.com/787217/how-to-edit-environment-variables-on-windows-10-or-11/).